# Constraint conflict because I can't deactivate constraint

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, collectionview

I have a CollectionView and I want to size it's height dynamical with the content.
I get an error because the setted constraint in the storyboard conflicts with the constraint
setted in my code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.addSubview(myCollectionView)
    //other constraints of collectionView
    collHeight = myCollectionView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 276)
    collHeight!.isActive = true
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
       //other stuff
        collHeight!.constant = collectionView.contentSize.height
        view.layoutIfNeeded()
 }
```

Error: https://pastebin.com/5yQh5hUP
I can't delete the constraint with Entf on it.
It only set's the number to 0. Can I deactivate it programmatically?

Comment: You don't think this might be worth paying attention to? "If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints`."

Comment: Also you've got no business setting a collection view constraint constant in `cellForItemAt`, that makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Select your conflicting constraint and check the "Remove at build time" option

[image]

2. Instead of creating your constraint in the `viewDidLoad` function, you can make an outlet of the constraint and just set change it's constant.

   ```
   @IBOutlet weak var collectionViewHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

   override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      view.addSubview(myCollectionView)
      // Set the constant
      collectionViewHeightConstraint.constant = 276 // Change this as you wish
   }
   ```

Comment: @Marro answer for your comment: First you should select the CollectionViewHeight constraint on the Storyboard which is making the trouble for your. Then on the right side you see the properties of it, if not you should open the Inspector. In the inspector select the "Size inspector" which has ruler icon. It that tab you will find the "Remove at build time option"

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to remove the storyboard constrains, or disable it?

```
for constraint in self.view.constraints {  
   constraint.isActive = false
}
```

while you can define id for your constrains and check for its value inside the loop.
Actually I am not fully aware of your newly added constraints, but you can change its constant or multiplier

```
for constraint in self.view.constraints {
    if constraint.identifier == "xyz" {
        constraint.multiplier = 0.5
    }
}
```